# SharePoint 2019 on premise - show profile image in people webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, people-search

We have recently moved to SP2019 on premise.

We have our user profiles syncing from AD and have just imported the associated staff images as well.

What is now a problem is getting the profile images to show in the people webpart.

Any help appreciated - remember this is on premise.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure the picture property in user profile has value as shown below:

[image]

Per my test it works well:

[image]

Sometimes it doesn't work, try to update the picture and check again.

Comment: All users are imported from AD and the Picture property is populated -there is not an option to change them - the user image is a staff image that must be used - the user does not have the option to change this image for security and Identification purposes.

Comment: If the user can't change the image, could you change it in user profile service application as an administrator?Whether all  users' image not showing correctly?

Comment: All user profiles images are showing and now behaving correctly. It seems to be a very long time for that information to prorogate. So no real solution. Thanks Julie